# addnote.php problem connect to android studio

Tags: php

```
<?php
$db_name = "....";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "192.168.56.1";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$db_name);
$response = array();
// check for required fields
$note_title = "test55";
$note_content = "test88";
// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes(note_title, note_content) VALUES('$note_title', '$note_content')");
// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);?>
```

what the problem for this php 
when you put in android studio the note not save in database.we use phpmyadmin,wampserver and put database in localhost .

Comment: GOOD Code indentation help understand the flow! You do realise that this code will ALWAYS execute the last `Required field(s) is missing` response and there appears to be no good reason for that code to be there

Comment: Did you actually cehck the content of the database?

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: While outside the scope of the question, it also appears your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.